# Rails - rendering a layout for a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view, partial

Here's some mockup code of what I am trying to do:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout "application"
end

class SomeController < ActionController::Base

  verify :method => :get, :only => [:index]
  def index
    @some_objects = Some.collect
  end

end

# Now in: views/some/index.html.erb

<% if @some_objects %>
  # use the application layout
  <%= render(:partial => 'some/objects', :locals => {:some_objects => @some_objects}) %>
<% else %>
  # use a different layout than application
  # some/sales_page --> views/some/_sales_page.html.erb
  # layouts/sales --> views/layouts/sales.html.erb
  <%= render('some/sales_page', :layout => 'layouts/sales') %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I am trying to render a different layout than application for the partial some/sales_page. What do I have to do?

Note: my Rails version is 2.3.11.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change layout only in controller layer.

```
class SomeController < ActionController::Base
  layout :choose_layout
  verify :method => :get, :only => [:index]
  def index
    @some_objects = Some.collect
  end

  private
  def choose_layout
    @some_objects = Some.collect
    @some_objects ? "application" : "different_layout"
  end
end
```

Comment: I down voted because `You can change layout only in controller layer.` is not accurate. The `render` method accepts a template.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy, the `render` method takes a `:layout` option (essentially the way you have it your example), however your layout can live in the same directory as the calling file and it uses the partial naming conventions (i.e. start with an underscore). So in the case of your example if would be something along the following lines:

```
#In: views/some/index.html.erb

<% if @some_objects %>
  # use the application layout
  <%= render(:partial => 'objects', :locals => {:some_objects => @some_objects}) %>
<% else %>
  <%= render(:partial => 'sales_page', :layout => 'sales_layout') %>
<% end %>
```

The contents of your `views/some` folder will then be as follows:

```
views/some/index.html.erb
views/some/_objects.html.erb
views/some/_sales_page.html.erb
views/some/_sales_layout.html.erb
```

For a little bit more info on the subject, have a look at [this](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/8/3/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-partials-get-layouts), [this](http://railsonedge.blogspot.com/2008/04/dry-up-your-views-with-layouts-for-your.html) and [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html).